# Generate a random number or null

Tags: c#

I want to generate a random number or null. So lets say i have the option to fill in a number or leave a field blank (null) and now i wna tot generate one of the two. Generating a random number is easy using the Random class but i'm not sure how to let mij function return null occasionally. I  hope someone has a good idea in stead of always return null if the number generated is divisable through lets say 3 or another static number. the number that are generated will be used for indexes of arrays and the arrays are reasonably small. Lets say between 2 and 10 items.

Comment: Step 1) Generate the number. Step 2) See if the number generated satisfies your condition and, if it does, return null, else return the number. -- What's the difficulty?

Comment: ..or use a second number generator that will return two options... based on that, return null or a random number

Comment: Generate a random number and maybe when its negative return null.

Comment: The thing that's missing here is a distribution definition. How often would you like to see nulls, compared to actual integers? Once you answer that, you can come up with a matching algorithm. The two-step approach that was suggested here is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following my comment above, I would suggest you generate a first random number between n options (based on how many odds you want the number to be null) and based on that outcome, decide to return null or a random number.

The function since can return a nullable int, must declare the type as nullable using `int?`.

this is an example using that strategy:

```
private void caller(){
    Random rnd = new Random();
    //generate 100 random numbers from a caller
    for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
        this.getNumber(rnd);
}    

private int? getNumber(Random rnd, int oddsOfBeingNull = 2){
    int nullOrNumber  = rnd.Next(1, oddsOfBeingNull);
    //if it's == 1, return null
    if(nullOrNumber == 1)
      return null;
    //else return a random number between 1-100
    return rnd.Next(1, 100);        
}
```

}

Comment: OP: Of course, you would _not_ create a new `Random` in each method call.

Comment: thanks, I edited my answer to include a caller and the random generator being passed as an argument

Comment: Thamls for this one. And sorry for the late reaction but i was on vacation :D the two steap approach also works because i have that one now but i like this one better because otherwise i always miss some numbers.

Answer (score 3):

User for example a `negative` one for null. Maybe like this:

```
Random r = new Random();
int? randomNumber;

randomNumber = r.Next(-1, 3); //put whatever range you want in here from negative to positive
            
if(randomNumber == -1)
{
    randomNumber = null;
}
```

Comment: Tnx for this one is also a nice solution. But with the high number of possitive numbers the  probability of hitting negatives will get lower. Or i need to increase the negative number but...

Answer (score 1):

This is a special edge case. The null scenario you wish to add to the possible results is something you will have to define its probability.
I think it is reasonable and quite easy to pre-define a range for which you will return null to the user.
Define this range based on the desired probability and add a simple range check after querying the random function.
something like this:

```
private double? Random()
{
    var r = new Random();
    var result = r.NextDouble();
    if (result > 0.9)
        return null;
    return result;
}
```